# Are there any non-GPL linux package managers?

Tags: linux, package-management, free-software

I'm looking for a linux package manager for personal project. 
The main criterium is non-GPL (and it's variants) license.
So far I've managed to find that only Slackware's pkgtools meet this rule, but there surely must be others!

I like pkgtools, but I like choice even more ;p

What other - non-GPL - linux package management systems are there? (*I assume the list to be short so it's not an open ended question)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pkgsrc`](http://www.pkgsrc.org/) is BSD-licensed and [can be used by a large number of OSes, also GNU/Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkgsrc):

> `pkgsrc` can be used either with command-line tools to install, remove and otherwise manipulate prebuilt binary packages, or to build packages from source where additional build options may be provided or features enabled or disabled.

[*The `pkgsrc` guide*](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/) tells you how to [bootstrap `pkgsrc`](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/platforms.html#bootstrapping-pkgsrc).

It [also features](http://pkgsrc.se/pkgtools/pkgin) [`pkgin`](http://pkgin.net/), what is supposed to be an `apt`/`yum`-like tool for maintaining binary package installs (of packages that could have been built from `pkgsrc`).

Comment: isn't pkgsrc a framework for building packages (that can't be used for base system) which just happens to be able to manage those?

Comment: I might not understand what you're looking for in a package manager – What do you miss in `pkgsrc`?

Comment: can it compile and manage a base system? can I use different libc implementation? link statically?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I doubt there are packages for this yet, but *as a framework* it probably allows you to do that – [Look](http://pkgsrc.se/wip/linux-kernel) [here](http://pkgsrc.se/wip/sysvinit), [for](http://pkgsrc.se/wip/linux-modutils) [example](http://pkgsrc.se/wip/net-tools) (and linking statically should be possible, too, as [this](http://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/platforms.html#linux) indicates)

Answer (score 2):

Linux brew (http://linuxbrew.sh) is under the BSD 2-Clause License.

It's sort of interesting in the sense of it being root independent, though that might not have been a requirement for you...